# Unable to use facebook login with passport JS

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, passport.js, facebook-login

I am trying to implement facebook login to my node app using passport JS. I am able to redirect to login page when I entered the get URL related to the request

[image]

But after entering my credentials I am unable to get the expected information viz. profile data of my account. Instead I am getting below screen as a response

[image]

In addition to that, I am unable to add my localhost URLs to the valid OAuth redirect URIs section

[image]

Please look into this and suggest me a fix.

Passport Setup for Facebook.

```
const { Strategy } = require("passport-facebook");
require("../env-config");

const initializePassportFacebook = passport => {
  const {
    FACEBOOK_APP_ID: clientID,
    FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET: clientSecret
  } = process.env;
  passport.use(
    new Strategy(
      {
        clientID,
        clientSecret,
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3001/user/facebook/callback"
      },
      (token, tokenSecret, profile, done) => {
        return done(null, profile);
      }
    )
  );
};

module.exports = initializePassportFacebook;
```

User routes(will be preceded http://localhost:3001/user)

```
userRouter.get("/facebook", passport.authenticate("facebook"));

userRouter.get(
  "/facebook/callback",
  passport.authenticate("facebook", { failureRedirect }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(successRedirect);
  }
);
```